# application of finite state machine in self service washing machine

Tags: visual-c++, matlab

i'm learning about Finite State MAchine(FSM)..can you help me with how the machine operates and the functional state diagram about the operation of this machine using FSM.

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend the book [Practical UML Statecharts in C/C++, Second Edition: Event-Driven Programming for Embedded Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750687061) if you don't find internet resources sufficient.

The author have implemented a [state machine framework](http://www.state-machine.com/) that might be suitable for your application as well (I have not used the framework myself though).